# How to Post Message to Slack Using System User?

Tags: slack, slack-salesforce-app, slack-app

We are using the `Slack: Post Message` Apex Action in Flow to publish a Slack Message when an field value is changed on Opportunity:

[image]

When the message is posted on Slack, it shows that it is posted by the user who made the change to the Opportunity record. However, we would prefer the record be posted by a system user instead.

1. Is there a way to make messages posted using the `Slack: Post Message` Apex Action in Flow post using a system user instead of the logged in Salesforce user?
2. If not, is there another way to accomplish posting a Slack message from a Salesforce Flow by a system user and include specific fields?

Note, I did find this question, which might be an option, but I haven't explored this yet:

[Send message to Slack without sending the record](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/392926/send-message-to-slack-without-sending-the-record)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the Managed Package app [Salesforce for Slack](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FnD9mUAF&tab=r) in your org.

Since Salesforce acquired Slack, there are native integrations that are available, and your requirement could be easily met with it.

Lets me walkthrough you how!

1. Make sure you enable Slack in your org. You will go to **Set up | Slack** to enable it. Below is what you should see if enabled.

[image]

2. Next, Make sure you Enable **Sales Cloud for Slack** from the setup page, as shown above
3. Then there is Sales Cloud for Slack Set up page that walks through the permissions set up you will need

[image]

4. Finally, in your Slack instance, find the app `Salesforce for Slack App`. This will land you to a new marketing page. On that page find the link under card `Salesforce for Slack`.
5. The link should ask you to log in to your Salesforce App.
6. Now, in your flows, you should start seeing the below actions

[image]

7. Finally, you should be able to see the below to configure the user you want the action where you can configure desired behavior.

Note you can even adjust layouts using this approach!

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mohith, appreciate the detail.