# Why is my Send Slack Message getting stuck and not posting to Slack?

Tags: slack, slack-salesforce-app, slack-app

I have created a Flow with a Send To Slack action when I changed an Opportunity. I have configured the action according to these instructions:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_actions_slack_send_message.htm&type=5

My Flow is executing the `Sent To Slack` action on an asynchronous path, and I've also tested it on a scheduled path. In both cases, when I change the Opportunity, the message does not post in Slack. I can see the record being queued up in `Time-Based Workflow` but when the time comes to run it, the Scheduled Date is passed and rescheduled for the future, suggesting that there is some kind of error.

I enabled debugging for my user, but I don't see any errors in the debug log.

Our Slack setup is configured per the instructions in this answer:

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/396438/12290

The one part that has me confused is this:

[image]

I'm trying to post to a specific Slack channel. My user is a Member, so I should be able to choose "User Who Runs the Flow". But this doesn't work, maybe because Record Trigger Flows run in System Context, and therefore the call is still from "Slack App".

If I choose "Slack App", which is what I prefer, this doesn't work either, but it leads to the question, how do I add "Slack App" as a member of the Slack channel?

What can I check to see why my message is not posting on Slack?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you authenticated to the Salesforce from Slack as that user? Also want to make sure you provided all the necessary permissions to the user?

Comment: Yes, my user (admin) has been authenticated, and is member of all Slack permission sets. How does one add "Slack App" as a member of the Slack channel, per the instructions? I cannot find any user like that in Slack.

Comment: Simply invite the bot with @bot name!

Comment: I can help with this over a video call if you email me at mohith.shrivastava@salesforce.com.

Comment: Thank you, Mohith. Sent you an email.

Answer (score 0):

As the instructions say make sure to invite the Slack Bot to your Channel.

You can do this by using `@<App Name>` in the messages. To be clear use the `@` symbol and also use the App Name.