# Salesforce- Slack

Tags: slack-salesforce-app

We are using the Slack: Post Message Apex Action in Flow to publish a Slack Message when an field value is changed on Opportunity. The default fields when the message is posted in Slack are:

`Close Date/Opportunity Stage/Next Step`

would like to change these/add fields but it is not clear where this can be done.
Appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community. [See related](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/396436/how-to-post-message-to-slack-using-system-user) - that managed package has been withdrawn from appexchange